# How to calculate the first (and second) eigenvalue of Laplacian-Beltrami on round sphere?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the round sphere
$$
S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3, x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\}
$$
with induced metric. I know the first (and second) non-trivial eigenvalue of Laplacian should be
$$
\lambda_1=\frac{2}{r^2} ~~(=\lambda_2)
$$
from [Hersch's paper](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eclayton/translations/hersch.pdf). But I don't know how to calculate it.  In fact, I know few paper or book talking about the detail calculation of eigenvalue on some special manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sphere, you can make the following two observations:

1. There is a one-to-one correspondence between eigenfunctions $u_k$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ of the Laplace-Beltrami and homogeneous harmonic functions $v(x) = |x|^m u_k(x/|x|)$ of homogeneity $m$, where
   $$
   m = \frac{2-n + \sqrt{(2-n)^2 + 4 \lambda_k}}{2}.
   $$
   This can be seen by computing, for a homogeneous function $v(x) = |x|^m u(x/|x|)$, the Laplacian $\Delta v$ in polar coordinates: $$\Delta v = v_{rr} + \frac{n-1}{r}v_r + \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^{n-1}} v = r^{m - 2} [m(m - 1) + m (n - 1) + \Delta_{S^{n-1}} u].$$
   So $v$ is harmonic if and only if $u$ is an eigenfunction, and the eigenvalue is related to the homogeneity $m$ by this formula. [Actually if you are careful you'll note that for every eigenvalue there are two choices of $m$ which work, one positive and one negative; the negative one will not be harmonic at $0$.]
2. All homogeneous harmonic functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are polynomials (Liouville's theorem). There is at least one homogeneous harmonic polynomial of every integer homogeneity, and you can more generally count/classify them. So the eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami are obtained by taking $m$ a (nonnegative) integer. The first one, $m = 0$, corresponds to the constant eigenfunction with $\lambda = 0$. For $m = 1$, there are $n$ linearly independent linear harmonic polynomials, giving $n$ linearly independent eigenfunctions on $S^{n-1}$ with eigenvalue $n-1$. You can keep computing higher eigenvalues and eigenfunctions similarly.

This does not work on any manifold other than the sphere.